# HTTPS to HTTP on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an API deployed to an EC2 instance (AWS), which is based on HTTP.
Now, there is a front-end that wants to access my API. The front-end is a web app hosted on another server, which is based on HTTPS. Due to the difference in the protocols (at least it is what I can guess), the browser complains about the security.

Now I want to create an API gateway, which connects HTTPS and my HTTP API.
Is there an easy way to do it with AWS?

Comment: "Now I want to create an API gateway, which connects HTTPS and my HTTP API. Is there an easy way to do it with AWS?"  Yes, use AWS API Gateway and a free AWS SSL certificate. You could also place a load balancer, or CloudFront, in front of your EC2 intance and use a free SSL certificate from AWS.

Comment: You could also have a free SSL cert directly on the EC2 depending on your deployment stack.

Answer (score 2):

There are some simple methods to make secured connection.

1. No extra cost. Create free SSL certificate using cert bot or something else, integrate it in your application API in EC2 (in case you point your app dirrectly to EC2 instance).
2. No extra cost. [Create free SSL certificate with API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#generate-client-certificate) and configure your API to use that certificate.
3. (Recommended) Generate certificate using AWS Certificate Manager. Create a load balancer and create HTTPS listener on port 443, add that cert to the listener and. Create rule in that https listener to forward request to a target group  with your instance (or attach an auto scaling group). You can also use method 1 to make connection between your EC2 and your load balancer secured.
4. Similar to method 2, but add certificate to CloudFront, make your load balancer an endpoint of Cloudfront.

If you want to use API Gateway, It's recommended to use Lambda instead of EC2. Lambda is high availability, lower cost, automatically scalable and easier to integrate with API Gateway.

Try [this](https://codethief.io/aws-connect-api-gateway-to-ec2/) if you still want to use EC2

Comment: Why would one want to add a load balancer?. I assume it costs extra cash per month?. Is there a way to do so via AWS without load balancer?